# How do I write Junit Test for method like this, for context I have included a current test I have

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to test the `getOrGenerateID()` method below in the `generateClass` class. I am struggling with writing a test that will test the logic of the method.

```
public class generateClass {
    public static String getOrGenerateID() {
        if (map.containsKey("TestMapKey")) {   //check if map has a key
            return map.get("TestMapKey");     // return the value for the key
        }
    }
}
```

**The Unit Test I have written so far:**

```
public void getOrGenerateIDTest() {
    map.put("TestMapKey", "TestMapValue");
    String newID = getOrGenerateID();
    Assertions.assertTrue(map.containsKey("TestMapKey"));
    Assertions.assertEquals("TestMapValue", map.get("TestMapKey");
}
```

Comment: Your `GenerateClass` code is incomplete at the moment, so it's hard to tell what it does in the event that `map` does not contain `TestMapKey`. Generally speaking, though, your tests should reflect what you want the method to do from the point of view of the caller. For example, you might test that the first time you call getOrGenerateId(), you get a new value, and on subsequent calls you get the same value or different values (depending on what you want).

Comment: Further advice, though: 1) by convention, Java classes are named with a capital letter at the start and you don't need to say that it's a class (e.g. `Generator` or `IdGenerator` would be better); 2) it's much harder to test static methods, because you have to reset them between tests. With non-static methods, you can create a new instance of the class under test, so it's always in a pristine state.

Answer (score 0):

Your `generateClass` class (BTW, by convention, Java class start with a capital, as in, `GenerateClass`) is missing the `map` variable.

Because your method is static, so must the variable be also. For example:

```
public class GenerateClass {
    static final Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap();

    public static String getOrGenerateID() {
        if (map.containsKey("TestMapKey")) {   //check if map has a key
            return map.get("TestMapKey");     // return the value for the key
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you make the `map` variable package-scoped, you can assign values in the test, to test. For example:

```
public void getOrGenerateIDTest() {
    GenerateClass.map.put("TestMapKey", "TestMapValue");
    String newID = GenerateClass.getOrGenerateID();
    Assertions.assertTrue(GenerateClass.map.containsKey("TestMapKey"));
    Assertions.assertEquals("TestMapValue", map.get("TestMapKey");
}
```